# Kue only run the job once

Tags: kue

Im using kue to schedule a job, but its only is executed the first time.

Here is my code:

```
Queue.clear(function(error, response) {
    var job = Queue
                .createJob("sendStatus")
                .priority('normal')
                .removeOnComplete(true);
    Queue.every('20 seconds', job);
    Queue.process("sendStatus", telegram.checkStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to call `done()` on `checkStatus`